# If $a,b,c,d,e$ be real number other than $-2≤a≤b≤c≤d≤e≤2$, prove the following inequation $\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-b}+\frac{1}{d-c}+\frac{1}{e-d}≥4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Question**
If $a,b,c,d,e$ be real numbers $-2≤a≤b≤c≤d≤e≤2$, prove the following inequation
$$\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-b}+\frac{1}{d-c}+\frac{1}{e-d}≥4$$

I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz like
$$\left(\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-b}+\frac{1}{d-c}+\frac{1}{e-d}\right)(b-a+c-b+d-c+e-d)≥16$$
I think I should prove it using $-2≤a≤b≤c≤d≤e≤2$, but I'm confused about how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're right there. Notice that the second bracket simplifies to $ e - a$, which is $ \leq 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cauchy-Schwarz** : $\left(\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-b}+\frac{1}{d-c}+\frac{1}{e-d}\right)(e-a)≥16$
From $−2≤a≤b≤c≤d≤e≤2$,  $e-a≤4$
∴$\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-b}+\frac{1}{d-c}+\frac{1}{e-d}≥4$

Answer (score 1):

$w=b-a, x=c-b,y=d-c, z=e-a$

you have four non-negative numbers $w,x,y,z$ that sum to $e-a\leq 4,$ so
$w+x+y+z \leq 4$   and $\frac{1}{w+x+y+z} \geq \frac{1}{4}$

The harmonic mean of thew is smaller then the arithmetic mean, for
$$ \frac{16}{w+x+y+z}  \leq \frac{1}{w} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} +\frac{1}{z} $$

This book I have refers to an AM-HM inequality for positive real numbers, if there are $n$ numbers

(with equality only when all the numbers are equal)

$$ \left(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \right)  \left( \frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{x_n} \right) \geq n^2   $$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva  my letters are the differences (in order) of each pair of the original letters $a,b,c,d,e$ and are positive. The OP allowed consecutive letters to be equal, but that makes the ratio he gives undefined.